# How do I drag and copy a button to a container without completely transferring the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a simple game (similar to Blockly and Scratch) that involves drag and drop. Currently, I am able to drag the button to a target container. However, the button gets completely transferred to another container. What I want to achieve is something like copy-pasting - from one container to another (basically drag-and-copy). I understand I have to clone it and give it a new ID but to no avail.

Here are the relevant codes:
HTML and JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Game</title>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/playmaze.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body id="page-top">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordion_sidebar">
            <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15"><i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i></div>
                <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3">Directions</div>
            </a>

            <form action="/" method="post">
                <div class="directions">
                    <input type="button" class="draggable" id="forward" value="Forward" draggable="true"></button>
                    <input type="button" class="draggable" id="backward" value="Backward" draggable="true"></button>
                    <input type="button" class="draggable" id="right" value="Right" draggable="true"></button>
                    <input type="button" class="draggable" id="left" value="Left" draggable="true"></button>
                    <input type="button" class="draggable" id="repeat" value="Repeat" draggable="true"></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </ul>

        <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div id="content">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                                <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                    <h2 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary" id="maze_name">Maze</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="container">
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Reset"></button>
                                    <input type="submit" id="run" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Run"></button>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
const draggables = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable')
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container')

// loop through each of the draggables (aka buttons)
draggables.forEach(draggable => {
    draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
        console.log('drag start')
        draggable.classList.add('dragging')
    })

    draggable.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
        draggable.classList.remove('dragging')
    })
})

containers.forEach(container => {
    container.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
        // by default, dropping inside an element is disabled
        e.preventDefault()
    
        // return of the getDragAfterElement function
        // e.clientY = y position of the mouse on the screen
        const afterElement = getDragAfterElement(container, e.clientY)

        // get the element you are currently dragging
        const draggable = document.querySelector('.dragging')
        
        // clone the dragged element 
        const draggableClone = document.getElementById(draggable).cloneNode(true)
        
        // give new ID 
        draggableClone.id = "cloneId"
        
        if (afterElement == null) {
            // append the element that is currently being dragged
            container.appendChild(draggableClone)
        } else {
            container.insertBefore(draggableClone, afterElement)
        }
    })
})

// determine the mouse position when dragging elements and 
// return whichever element our mouse position is directly after 
function getDragAfterElement(container, y) {
    // array 
    const draggableElements = [...container.querySelectorAll('.draggable:not(.dragging)')]
    
    // reduce -> loop through the list of draggableElements and determine 
    // which single element is directly after the mouse based on the y position (retrieved from the event)
    return draggableElements.reduce((closest, child) => {
        const box = child.getBoundingClientRect()
        const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2
        if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
            return { offset: offset, element: child }
        } else {
            return closest
        }
    }, { offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY }).element
}
</script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container
{
    background-color: #ffeaf0;
    padding: 1rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
}

.draggable
{
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: move;
    border-radius: 1rem;
}

.draggable.dragging
{
    opacity: .5;
}

.grid-wrapper
{
    display: grid;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 100px);
}

.grid-item
{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 2px solid rgb(139,69,19);
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.directions {
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 20px 10px 20px;
}

.btn-lg {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#forward {
    background-color: #98e690;
    border:#98e690;
    color: #404040;
}

#backward {
    background-color: #ff85a2;
    border: #ff85a2;
    color: #404040;
}

#right {
    background-color: #92dff3;
    border: #45b3e0;
    color: #404040;
}

#left {
    background-color: #fdfd96;
    border: #fdfd96;
    color: #404040;
}

#repeat {
    background-color: #CC99FF;
    border: #CC99FF;
    color: #202020;
}

#reset {
    background-color: black;
    border: #CC99FF;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 6rem;
}

#run {
    background-color: #32CD32;
    border: #32CD32;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 6rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clone the dragged html element:

So your code should be:

```
const draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
let currentDraggableClone = null;
let currentAfterElement = null;
let currentContainer = null;
// loop through each of the draggables (aka buttons)
draggables.forEach((draggable) => {
  draggable.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {
    console.log("drag start");
    draggable.classList.add("dragging");
  });

  draggable.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
    if (currentContainer === null || currentDraggableClone === null) return;
    //Random ID
    currentDraggableClone.id =
      currentDraggableClone.id + Math.random() * 100000000;
    if (currentAfterElement == null) {
      // append the element that is currently being dragged
      currentContainer.appendChild(currentDraggableClone);
    } else {
      currentContainer.insertBefore(currentDraggableClone, currentAfterElement);
    }
    currentDraggableClone.classList.remove("dragging");
    draggable.classList.remove("dragging");
  });
});

containers.forEach((container) => {
  container.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
    // by default, dropping inside an element is disabled
    e.preventDefault();
    currentContainer = container;
    currentAfterElement = getDragAfterElement(container, e.clientY);
    const draggable = document.querySelector(".dragging");
    if (
      draggable !== null &&
      (currentDraggableClone === null ||
        currentDraggableClone.id !== draggable.id)
    ) {
      currentDraggableClone = draggable.cloneNode(true);
    }
  });
});

// determine the mouse position when dragging elements and
// return whichever element our mouse position is directly after
function getDragAfterElement(container, y) {
  // array
  const draggableElements = [
    ...container.querySelectorAll(".draggable:not(.dragging)")
  ];

  // reduce -> loop through the list of draggableElements and determine
  // which single element is directly after the mouse based on the y position (retrieved from the event)
  return draggableElements.reduce(
    (closest, child) => {
      const box = child.getBoundingClientRect();
      const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2;
      if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
        return { offset: offset, element: child };
      } else {
        return closest;
      }
    },
    { offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY }
  ).element;
}
```

Comment: hi, the button now doesn't get completely transferred. however, upon pasting it into to the container, it is multiplied.

Comment: Hi, see if this version works. I only needed to append the new element on drag end.